# Best way to get values from a external file in java

Tags: java

I have a java code which I'm currently running as a jar. This code checks for a specific file in the given directory which is currently hard coded in the code.

To give more flexibility and not to touch the code. I would like to have the folers list managed by a different file and the code reads this config file and gets the list of folders each time and execute it.

I would like to know which is the best possible option of maintaining the folder list outside the code so that anyone can update it. Can a properties be used for this ? can we dynamically take values from a property file

Comment: Yes, a Properties file seems to be a reasonable approach to what you seem to be asking.

Comment: Have you try it? If you did, what did you find? Any problems?

Comment: If by "dynamically" you mean see the changed values when somebody modifies the file -- then no, you can't. You would need to implement this by youself.

Comment: Pass the directory name (and possibly file name) as command line arguments to the program, and then create a script to execute the program. The users can then modify the script to pass whatever directory and file name they choose.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have the `java.util.Properties` that allow you to load flat key/value data from external resources.

If you need something that can be dynamically updated, there's also the more sophisticated [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) library. This one allows you to:

1. Keep data organized in tree structures (it's a tree of nodes, each node storing its own key/value preferences).
2. Make use of basic types (primitive types, strings and binary data).
3. Make use of platform-dependent "native" stores transparently (under the hood, it's going to use the file system on Unix systems and registries on Windows by default).
4. Plug in your own backing store if needed.
5. Get any data changes performed within the application persisted transparently.
6. Register node/preference change listeners and react to any change if needed.

The API is quite old and hasn't been updated, but it doesn't mean it's deprecated. It is used mostly with GUI applications (notably, IntelliJ IDEA was storing its configuration using Preferences the last time I checked).

There's also an attempt to revive this library that I made with a project called [cross-preferences](https://github.com/adobe-research/cross-preferences) by integrating modern distributed config stores (such as *zookeeper*, *etcd* or *consul*) as backing stores for `java.util.prefs.Preferences` and providing a web console for preference management.

Comment: if you go with the properties file approach, I think these examples are good: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: @Jeutnarg is this comment intended for me or the OP? I find it more suited on the question above.

Comment: the question leads me to think that the OP will need some code examples, your answer encompasses any answer I would have written, and your answer included no code. Therefore, I would be wrong to leave no code whatsoever, I would be wrong to answer separately, and I would be wrong to edit your answer. Considering this, I commented a link to a good tutorial for the OP, in case they use your answer. In direct answer to your question, it's for the OP, but only if this answer is the one they use.

Comment: @Jeutnarg Got it, makes sense now.